# 'Unterminated regular expression literal' error while parsing XML data from a foreign domain by javaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, syntax-error

So I'm starting this thread to fix a (likely syntax) error I encountered while implementing the answer by steven.yang at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9346188/search-xml-file-using-javascript).

I tried his suggestion [here](http://jsfiddle.net/A2S2S/1/), but got the error:

> Unterminated regular expression literal.

This looks like a minor thing to fix, but I myself am not sure how to fix it.

Thanks!

**update**

since using jsonp makes it access the xml file, would it be possible to tell the computer to ignore any errors, just return the content of the `<webcite_url>` tags?

Comment: What is your code that generates that error?

Comment: For beginners you have `dataType: JSONp` but the data looks actually more like an XML response, have you tried `dataType: XML`?

Comment: my code is at the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/A2S2S/1/)

Comment: you're right. that page is xml. ok so I tried `dataType: 'XML'` [here](http://jsfiddle.net/hwskc/2/), but the xml is not being parsed at all now

Answer (score 1):

This php script will copy an external xml file to your local server. This will then allow you to parse that file instead.

I'm just working on a project that involves working with external data- you'll just need to execute this script when you want to update the xml file.

```
<?php
/**
* Initialize the cURL session
*/
$ch = curl_init();
/**
* Set the URL of the page or file to download.
*/
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://*path/to/external.xml*');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$xml = curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
if (@simplexml_load_string($xml)) {
    /**
    * Create a new file
    */
    $fp = fopen('*desiredfilename*.xml', 'w');
    fwrite($fp, $xml);
    fclose($fp);
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The URL you're requesting isn't JSONP.

You get a syntax error when the browser tries to parse the XML response as Javascript.

Comment: or rather, it doesn't have to parse it as anything. I just need to be able to retrieve the content between the `<webcite_url>` tags, so if it can parse it as a string, that'd be fine.

Comment: @AnthonyNewman: No; you cannot circumvent the same-origin policy.  You need server-side code.

Comment: ah that again.... but seriously, in my original code with that regex error that pointed to the xml file I was looking for, it clearly accessed that file, so are you sure?

Comment: No; it can't be accessed.  You can execute it as Javascript, but _you cannot read arbitrary content from another domain_. Period.