# Text variable as html from file from another site

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I try to use text variable from file from another site. Site contains only one value - number. On my site I added IFRAME:

```
<iframe id="counter" src="http://xxxx/counter.txt">
```

Then I was trying to take value from IFRAME by using this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
onload = function () {
    var ball = document.getElementById('counter');
    var div = document.getElementsByTagName('XcounterX')[0];
    div.innerHTML = ball;
};
</script>
```

The last point is to display var as html value by:

```
<XcounterX> Result </XcounterX>
```

Full html:

```
<body>
<iframe id="counter" src="http://xxxx/counter.txt">

<script type="text/javascript"> 
onload = function () {
    var ball = document.getElementById('counter');
    var div = document.getElementsByTagName('XcounterX')[0];
    div.innerHTML = ball;
};
</script>

<XcounterX> Result </XcounterX>
</body>
```

Unfortunately it doesn't work. Java complitly is something new for me. Can you help? I also try:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
    url: "http://xxxx/counter.txt",
    dataType: 'html',
    context: document.body,
    success: function(data){
      $("#XcounterX").empty;
      $("#XcounterX").html(data);
  }
});
</script>

<div id='XcounterX'></div>
```

Same result. :(

Comment: Do you have access to the server that hosts `counter.txt`?

Comment: Yes. More - file is public: if you put "http://xxxx/counter.txt" in browser you will get result

Comment: No, I mean can you change things on that server, edit files etc.

Comment: Yes I can. What should I do?

Comment: Ohh, they are on the same origin, sorry, my thinking was on the wrong path.

Comment: This should help, there is a "text" data type: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10112509/reading-a-text-file-with-jquery

Answer (score 0):

If I had your code, I would test those things (without conviction).

#### 1. JS pure

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
  onload = function () {
    var ball = document.getElementById('counter');
    var div = document.getElementsByTagName('XcounterX')[0];
    div.innerHTML = ball.innerHTML;
  };
</script>
```

#### 2. jQuery

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
      url: "http://xxxx/counter.txt",
      success: function(data){
        $("#XcounterX").empty();
        $("#XcounterX").html(data);
      }
    });
  </script>

  <div id='XcounterX'></div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, none of these options work. Is this possible at all? Both sites have same origin. One is (https://xxxx/counter.txt) and second is (https://xxxx/yyyy). I try to take result from https://xxxx/counter.txt and display it on https://xxxx/yyyy