# How to check multiple URLs status code in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am checking URLs status codes in JavaScript. I am able to do it writing code to check status for one by one URL. But I have 100+ URLs which make my code too long if go for all 100+ URLs. Is there any way where I can pass a list of urls in JavaScript using .xls or .txt files which contains all URLs and iterate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to do it at frontend, I paste you some link to give you the direction.

the process is `read text file ---> check url`

1. read text file

You can reference this question [Reading a text file with jQuery [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10112551/2063914) to do the trick.

2. check url

You can reference this question [Checking if a URL is broken in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3915698/2063914).

So with these two reference question, I use a simple pseudo-code to tell you how to combine it and make it work.

```
function UrlExists(url, cb){
    jQuery.ajax({
        url:      url,
        dataType: 'text',
        type:     'GET',
        complete:  function(xhr){
            if(typeof cb === 'function')
               cb.apply(this, [xhr.status]);
        }
    });
}

$.get('YOUR_URL_FILE.txt', function(data) {
  // here I assume your data is this format:
  // url1
  // url2
  // url3
  var urls = data.split('\n');
  urls.forEach(function(url) {
    UrlExists(url, function(status){
      if(status === 200){
         // file was found
      }
      else if(status === 404){
         // 404 not found
      }
    });
  })
}, 'text');
```

Hope it helps you.