# How to update table content in all HTML pages?

Tags: html, css

I am a new developer.

I am making a website and it will contain a lot of pages, more likely 100 or more. In all those pages I have inserted HTML tables.

Now how can I update all table content at once? Without editing hundreds of pages?

I have inserted links into the table but I need to update the links in all pages.
this is the table I inserted in all pages.

```
<table>
    <tr><th>Recomended</th></tr>
    <tr><td><a href="http://example.com" target="_blank">example</a></td></tr>
    <tr><td><a href="http://example.com" target="_blank">example</a></td></tr>
    <tr><td><a href="http://example.com" target="_blank">example</a></td></tr>
    <tr><td><a href="http://example.com" target="_blank">example</a></td></tr>
    <tr><td><a href="http://example.com" target="_blank">example</a></td></tr>
    <tr><td><a href="http://example.com" target="_blank">example</a></td></tr>
    <tr><td><a href="http://example.com" target="_blank">example</a></td></tr>
    <tr><td><a href="http://example.com" target="_blank">example</a></td></tr>
    <tr><td><a href="http://example.com" target="_blank">example</a></td></tr>
    <tr><td><a href="http://example.com" target="_blank">example</a></td></tr>
    <tr><td><a href="http://example.com" target="_blank">example</a></td></tr>
    <tr><td><a href="http://example.com" target="_blank">example</a></td></tr>
    <tr><td><a href="http://example.com" target="_blank">example</a></td></tr>
    <tr><td><a href="http://example.com" target="_blank">example</a></td></tr>
</table>
```

How can I update example.com?

Comment: How are the pages generated?

Comment: that purely depends on how you have designed your application. if all of them are static, use find and replace :P

Comment: if you are using code behind - hande the content there. if not - use code behind.

Comment: you could also use javascript with a solution like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18192777/create-html-table-from-text-file-using-javascript

Comment: This is why we use programming languages like PHP, python, ruby on rails!

Answer (score 0):

First You should learn about a web programming language ( PHP for example ) instead of writing static HTML pages.

Second to make your site available thought the internet you will need to buy a hosting and domain name. Or start with [a free service](https://www.google.com/search?btnG=1&pws=0&q=free%20web%20hosting&gws_rd=ssl)

Comment: Why PHP specifically?

Comment: This was just an example of web programming language. Editing my answer to be more general :)

Comment: @webNeat there are several [free services](https://www.google.com/search?btnG=1&pws=0&q=free+web+hosting&gws_rd=ssl) where you can host you sites in the web

Comment: @Max yeah but free services could be used only to test new projects. A real project need a paid hosting and domain name.

Answer (score 0):

create one table.html file 
put your table in this htmlfile
use jquery.js
use jquery load function

```
$('#div1').load('table.html', function() {

       //callback
});
```

update only at once.

Comment: 1. JavaScript isn't tagged. 2. jQuery isn't tagged.

Comment: i think solution is best

Comment: @JamesDonnelly CSS is tagged - may the OP doesnt really know how to accomplish what he wants. In that case tags from him have less meaning.