# How to get text out of a text file and let it be shown inside a <table>?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to show some numbers of my txt files inside a [<table>](https://prnt.sc/nogvom)...
In theory the numbers should replace the 3 black rows...
I tried nearly anything: `<object>`, JavaScript, HTML etc...

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please post your code showing your attempt so far. See how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for help on writing a good question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create HTML table from text file using Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18192777/create-html-table-from-text-file-using-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

If you are providing your content with a server, you can use the Fetch API to fetch one of your files:

```
fetch('path/to/file.txt')
```

I would recommend storing data in a `.json` file rather than a `.txt` file.